# Solving an inequality that contains Log expressions

Tags: equation-solving

How can I solve the following inequality:

```
Log[1/2 + c^2] > (1.4) (30^5) 2^(4.5) 9 (0.6) (2.8) (1 + Log[3]) (1 +Log[ Log[c + 1]])
```

?

I tried `Reduce`, but my computer is still computing it (c is a real number).

Comment: Use for example `FindRoot[Log[1/2 + c^2] == 
  8230118400 Sqrt[2] (1 + Log[3]) (1 + Log[Log[1 + c]]), {c, 1/2}]` and plot the function around that value to get a hint ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for exact solutions you should substitute machine precission numbers by exact numbers. Therefore instead of your numerical coefficient I'd rather use this one:

```
 (7/5) (30^5) 2^(9/2) 9 (3/5) (14/4) (1 + Log[3])
 N[%]
```

> ```
> 10287648000 Sqrt[2] (1 + Log[3])
> 3.05326*10^10
> ```

This is a huge number so for the sake of simplicity instead of playing with it I'll use a coefficient `a` much smaller to demonstrate the main issue.

First assume the coefficient is `a == 1` and plot these two functions:

```
Plot[{ Log[1/2 + c^2], (1 + Log[Log[1 + c]])}, {c, 0, 2}, 
       PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Thick ]
```

[image]

We can see there are two solutions and `Log[1/2 + c^2]` tends to infinity faster. 
To show where the inequality is satisfied we use blue `Filling`:

```
Plot[ Log[1/2 + c^2] - (1 + Log[Log[1 + c]]), {c, 0, 2},  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
      PlotStyle -> Thick,  Filling -> {1 -> {0, {Red, Blue}}}]
```

[image]

Moreover regardless of the coefficient `a` we have

```
Limit[a (1 + Log[Log[c + 1]])/Log[1/2 + c^2], c -> Infinity]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

and if `a` gets larger then the upper range of the solution set starts with a larger number.
It seems there is a bug in `Reduce` when we work with inequalities, therefore we can use a simple equality instead. 
Now the case `a == 30`:

```
Reduce[ 30 (1 + Log[Log[c + 1]])/Log[1/2 + c^2] == 1, c, Reals]
```

> ```
> c == Root[{1 - 2 E^30 Log[1 + #1]^30 + 2 #1^2 &, 0.43820044934843508362}] || 
> c == Root[{1 - 2 E^30 Log[1 + #1]^30 + 2 #1^2 &, 1.35977747245195272715*10^35}]
> ```

Thus the inequality for `a == 30` is satisfied  for

> ```
>  0 < c < 0.43820044934843508362 || c > 1.35977747245195272715*10^35
> ```

for the original `a` the lower limit can be calculated as suggested by belisarius in the comment, while the upper one exceeds `$MaxNumber`.

Comment: thank you for your response !!!